# How to use 'await' inside a sync function?

Tags: typescript

I want to make an API like this:

```
class jsonReader {
  public async load()
  {
     // some code
  }
}

let reader = new jsonReader();

function foo(){
  await reader.load();
  // [ts] 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.
}
```

How can I use Async/Await inside a synchronous function call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You either make that function asynchronous as well and use `await` or use the promise from the returned function. All functions marked with `async` return `Promise<T>`. In your *shared* code the return type is `Promise<void>`, you can chain `then` to it.

```
function foo(){
  reader.load().then(() => /*your code here*/);
}
```

Comment: Note: that still makes `foo()` an asynchronous function, it just makes it an asynchronous function that isn't marked with the `async` keyword.

Comment: So there is no equivalent of .Result from the c# world

Comment: That is a property of [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) @MarshallTigerus. There is no equivalent property on a `Promise` because javascript, and by extension Typescript, discourages trying to block the thread because it is single threaded among other reasons.

Comment: @Igor Ok, so I am approaching the problem in the wrong way then.  I will reevaluate how this is being handled and see how we can better manage the issue.